# Issues with Office 365 Compliance center to audit SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, auditing

I have admin rights both on SharePoint online and compliance center in Office 365 tenant. but i am unable to use the auditing features and perform any actions. attached the screenshot with the error message.

let me know if there are any solutions. [image]

Comment: I'd recommend opening a support ticket in the admin portal.

Comment: thx, i did that already. posting here to see if someone has faced the similar issues or share any workarounds.

Comment: I used it a couple times today with no issues

Comment: i am interested to know what are the pre-requisites to see what exactly the problem i am facing ?

Answer (score 0):

The below are the pre-requisites for SharePoint Admins to have the auditing capabilities via Compliance center.

1. SharePoint admin.
2. Exchange online license (this is required because all the underlying cmnd are running under exchange online with in office 365)
3. the user should be a member of the organization management group (global admins will be having it as a default option).
4. if you are worried about the organization management role as it have several in-built permissions at a larger scope. so follow the below step:
5. create a separate group with permissions as view audit log results and then assign the user in to that group.

once all the pre-requisites are in-place then you should be able to view and export all the audit log entries both for SharePoint and One Drive.